# Android drawLines - line width differ

Tags: android, canvas, line, draw

I got stuck with canvas.drawLines().

My application displays track om map view, but the resulting lines are awful. 
Did anyone see such behavior? I.e, lines doesn't have same width, are not even "square", and are rhombus, and sometimes even disappear!

I've tested with for(){drawLine()} instead, and drawPath instead - same issue.

Screenshot took on 10" tablet 1280x800, Fujitsu. Lenovo tablet shows the same.

http://jpegshare.net/c8/1d/c81daa6cff15e3d14cb1268679bb1af1.png.html

```
    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);        
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //borderPaint.setAlpha(190);      


    fillPaint = new Paint();
    fillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    fillPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    fillPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

....
    canvas.drawLines(linepoints, 0, linepoints_count, borderPaint);
    canvas.drawLines(linepoints, 0, linepoints_count, fillPaint);
```

where linepoints is array of track lines to draw. Each line is set of 4 float numbers.

Comment: Well, I figured out my own problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out my problem. Hope this can help someone.

Before drawing lines, I do

```
canvas.translate(X, Y);
```

where X and Y values are HUGE. Like 10E+6..10E+7 or something.

When I draw lines, their xy values are huge too, but negative, hence in screen coordinates this xy+XY give something inside a screen - but this fact matters and produces issue described in my own first post.
Why this is happening? I found a clue. When drawLine algorithm tries to draw a line, it messes up with line coordinates (division, multiplication) and since machine arithmetic is limited in precision, algorithm gets wrong numbers.

```
How this was solved?
```

I dicarded canvas.translate(), and calulate screen coords on the fly, just before drawing.

Now, like that

```
screen_line_coords_x = line_coord_x - X; //X is offset applied in translate.           
screen_line_coords_y = line_coord_y - Y; //Y is offset applied in translate.

canvas.drawLine(screen_line_coords_x, screen_line_coords_y, ...); 
... or drawLines() or drawPath() - all give good results.
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I´m facing same thing. 
However, why are you using so huge offset, since the screen is about 1280x800 resolution ?
I believe that system coordinates gets too far from the real display coordinates causing wrong calculations at translation / rotation / scaling operations.

Try to revise your calculations in order to work inside of the display coordinates.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. If you are facing the same thing, what is the solution? and what ' translation / rotation / scaling operations' are you referring to?